# Sign in with Apple: How to know if user is signing up or signing in

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sign-in-with-apple

I would like to know if there is a way to find out *before I send the authorization request* if a user is signing up to my app with Apple for the first time, or if he/she is already registered and just signs in.

Basically I have a registration screen in my app, where a user can create two types of users and a login screen where both users can log in. I would like to keep the registration and login separate, so for that I need to know whether its a first sign in with apple.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what database you're using but for Cloud Firestore there is a Sign-in method that can be used with Apple.

[image: Apple Sign-in method.]